# Making sense out of Japanese proverbs

Tags: idioms, quotes

I was never able to make any sense out of the following Japanese proverbs or idiomatic expressions:

> 豆腐の角に頭をぶつけて死んでしまえ。
> 'Hit your head against a corner of a cake of tofu, and die.'
>
> ...の爪の垢を煎じて飲む。
> 'take extract from one's dirt/wax under the nail, and drink it'

They are nonsense to me, and the latter is also disgusting. How can you die in such a way? What is the purpose of drinking such thing? How can you make a sense out of them?

Comment: Maybe, the first one is saying you have a soft head. The second one might be like saying "eat s**t" in English...

Comment: The first reminds me of things along the lines of "could drown in a puddle"/"could trip over his own shadow" in English

Comment: The first one is from rakugo, which sometimes spout out nonsense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 豆腐の角に頭をぶつけて死んでしまえ。

Used to say that a person is so stupid (that he would believe this and real find a piece tofu to die). [(source)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ja/w/index.php?title=%E8%B1%86%E8%85%90&oldid=40284190#.E6.85.A3.E7.94.A8.E5.8F.A5)

> ...の爪の垢を煎じて飲む。

Use the dirt under the nail of ( some expertise ) as a drug, (you'll get some of his talent). [(source)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/148346/m0u/)

> 名人の爪の垢を煎じて飲めば少しは腕が上がるだろうに

It'll be hard to make any sense out of them if you see them alone. I'd recommend you to find some reference.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation. Can you please quote some source where I can get Japanese proverbs/idioms/phrases with a good English explanation.

Comment: @Mudassir I haven't come across one yet ...

Comment: @Mudassir What about a reference like this: http://www.languagerealm.com/japanese/japaneseproverbs.php ?  It's not as complete as a book would be... but, there are at least a few proverbs (with their explanations,) listed.

Comment: @summea: Thats really nice. Thanks for sharing.