# やった written as 殺った

Tags: nuances, japanese-to-english

In this sentence from 龍が如く極, localized title 'Yakuza Kiwami', (spoilers)

> Nishikiyama says 堂島組長殺ったのは…この俺だ！

where 殺った is pronounced as やった. I checked a kanji dictionary but didn't see a kunyomi of や(る) listed for 殺. Is writing やる as 殺る a slang usage? What's the difference in nuance between saying 殺した vs 殺った?

Comment: It is not official reading, but definitions of やる list this meaning with possible spelling 殺る, e.g. [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/やる) and [here](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/やる). The latter dictionary has it marked as 俗語 = colloquial and 婉曲 = euphemistic.

Comment: Compare the basic "to do" meaning of やる with the English expression "[to do (someone in)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do_in) → to kill someone".  Seems like a similar kind of metaphoric usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 殺る is a slangy usage of kanji used only when やる means "to kill". It's nonstandard, but common enough in manga and light novels.

殺す【ころす】 is a plain verb meaning "kill". 殺る【やる】 is a kind of euphemistic expression used by gangs and such to avoid directly mentioning "kill". English-speaking gangs may use "take care of [someone]" in a similar situation.

Related:

- [Is my understanding of やっちまった correct?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39111/5010)